# How can I know whether postgres is currently running synchronous or asynchronous replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3

I see from ps that:

```
postgres: wal sender process replicator X.X.X.X(38681) streaming 0/17AF5438
```

But is there any way for me to know whether it is synchronous or asynchronous? I made the relevant changes in postgresql.conf to switch from synchronous to asynchronous and restarted the postgres service, but I wanted to double check that the changes were parsed correctly and I am in fact running asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:

```
SHOW synchronous_standby_names;
```

on the master that's expected to have synchronous replicas reports a non-empty value, then synchronous replication is active.

Comment: Not being at all familiar with streaming replication, I presume you mean to execute this query on the primary -- or do(es) the slave(s) "know" the same?